# how to convert JSON dictionary to string value in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm new to Swift and I started working on a Swift 4 project with a PHP server.
I use Alamofire for requests, and print the data using `print()`. This is is what i'm getting:

`{"error":false,"n":"Raghad"}`

But when I want to convert it to String, it returns `""` (empty) and
 when I convert to boolean it returns the value correctly.

So, how can I fix it?

```
let wJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
print(wJSON["n"].stringValue)
print(wJSON["error"].boolValue)
```

Comment: If value for `"n"` isn't printed correctly then you haven't received response correctly. You get `false` for key `"error"` since `boolValue` is non-optional getter and therefore it returns default value which is `false`.

Comment: when I print the JSON object it printed correctly
print(wJSON)
it print {"error":false,"n":"Raghad"}
is I save it in the PHP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the `responseString` to `responseJSON`

Alamofire.request(Url!, method: .post, parameters: par).validate().`responseJSON` { response in if response.result.isSuccess { let wJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

and it's work

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `Decodable`, define a Struct that conforms to the `Decodable` protocol for your dictionary

```
struct Reply: Decodable {
    let error: Bool
    let n: String
}

let data = response.data
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Reply.self, from: data)
    print("\(result.n) \(result.error)")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Either your response is of type Data when you receive it (that's `data`) or you can do `let data = json.data(using: .utf8)` where `json` is your json string

Comment: I have use Alamofire for request from server
Alamofire.request(Url!, method: .post, parameters: par).validate().responseString {
     response in
     if response.result.isSuccess {
     let wJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(wJSON)
and it print 
{"error":false,"n":"Raghad"}
So I couldn't understand what the data for?

Comment: thank you I have correct my code 
.responseString  to responseJSON 
in Alamofire method in my code and it's work good